# How to enqueue multiple style sheets into my child theme in wordpress (oceanwp)

Tags: child-theme, wp-enqueue-style

I would like to import several styles sheets in my child theme (oceanWP). 
I succeed to do it with "@import" method but not with enqueueing scripts and styles.

**My child theme uses this "style.css" :**

```css
/*
 Theme Name:   oceanwp-child
 Theme URI:    https://monsite.com
 Description:  OceanWP WordPress theme example child theme.
 Author:       Phil
 Author URI:   https://voyageinitiartique.com
 Template:     oceanwp
 Version:      1.0.0
*/
/*@import url("./custom/navbar.css"); First, I try to import this with enqueueing method */
@import url("./custom/home.css");
@import url("./custom/voyages.css");
@import url("./custom/concept.css");
@import url("./custom/carnets.css");
@import url("./custom/contact.css");
@import url("./custom/articles.css");`
```

**Child theme function.php :**

```
function oceanwp_child_enqueue_parent_style() {
    // Dynamically get version number of the parent stylesheet (lets browsers re-cache your stylesheet when you update your theme)
    $theme   = wp_get_theme( 'OceanWP' );
    $version = $theme->get( 'Version' );
 // Load the stylesheet
       wp_enqueue_style( 'child-style', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/style.css', array ('oceanwp-style'), $version );
       wp_enqueue_style( 'child-navbar-style', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . './custom/navbar.css', array( 'oceanwp-style' ), $version );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'oceanwp_child_enqueue_parent_style' );
```

Other syntax tried without success:

```
wp_enqueue_style( 'child-navbar-style', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . './custom/navbar.css', array(), '1.0', 'all' );
```

Is someone can help me ? 
Thx !

Comment: If it does not load the stylesheet you wanted, what does it load instead? Is it giving a 404? What does the error console in the browser dev tools say?

Comment: The navigation bar is displayed but without expected styles. In code source, in the head the style sheet is present. In browser "css edit", message : "The requested resource <code class="url">/wp-content/themes/oceanwp-child./custom/navbar.css?ver=1.0</code> was not found on this server"

Comment: Ah, look at the URL it has a typo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You had the right idea, but made an unfortunate typo: `. './custom/navbar.css'`.

Removing the additional fullstop should correct the URL, otherwise you were succesfully enqueing a stylesheet, the code just enqueued the wrong URL due to the typo

Comment: ... And it works! Thank you :)